# UIView animation issue, when try no animatate images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have to show slideshow of images. But at one moment I know only current and previous images (because of memory management). I need to show the next image with animation (user can shoose the animation type). But I see no animation, just new image appears without animation.
Here is my code:

```
    UIImageView *prevImageView = [self getImageViewWithIndex:currentIndex];
    UIImageView *nowImageView = [self getImageViewWithIndex:newIndex];

    currentIndex = newIndex;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        [slideShowView addSubview:nowImageView];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [prevImageView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

I've tried different animation options. Tried to set new image to existing image view

```
nowImageView.image = newImage;
```

But that didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding or removing a view or setting the image of an UIImageView is not animatable within `animateWithDuration:...`.

### With `transitionWithView:...`

What you were probably trying to do is to use an UIView-transition (since you specified a transition option). Then you should use

```
transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

instead, like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:slideShowView
                  duration:4.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^
                { 
                    [prevImageView removeFromSuperview]; 
                    [slideShowView addSubview:nowImageView]; 
                }
                completion:NULL]; // You don't need the completion if you remove the previous image in the animation block.
```

---

### With `animateWithDuraion:...`

If you really wanted to use `animateWithDuraion:...` (maybe there are other animations happening at the same time) then you would have to animate some other property like the `alpha` of the view you are adding to have it fade in. Changing your code to do this would look something like this.

```
UIImageView *prevImageView = [self getImageViewWithIndex:currentIndex];
UIImageView *nowImageView = [self getImageViewWithIndex:newIndex];

currentIndex = newIndex;
[slideShowView addSubview:nowImageView];
nowImageView.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:4 
                 animations:^
    {
        nowImageView.alpha = 1.0;
    } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) 
    {
        [prevImageView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView transitionWithView:slideShowView 
                  duration:4.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                animations:^{
                    [prevImagesView removeFromSuperview];
                    [slideShowView addSubview:nowImageView];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

In this case, slideShowView is the superview of both prevImagesView and nowImagesView, acting as a container view.

Answer (score -1):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];

//you can choose type of animation here 

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

[prevImageView removeFromSuperview]; 
[slideShowView addSubview:nowImageView]; 

[UIView commitAnimations]; // commit your animation
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Why would this be any different from the code in the question?

Comment: That won't animate, just like the OP's original code won't animate. The other posters had the right solution of using transitionWithView...